# Higurashi Route Chapters

Tags: higurashi-when-they-cry

I was just wondering if the trend of the Higurashi Question Arcs having 12 chapters is continued throughout the Answer Arcs? I understand that the Question Arcs are overall longer but I'm not sure if this is a result of having more chapters in each game. Edit: I am referring to the Visual Novel series and the chapters contained with each game.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not clear what you are looking for an answer to. Are you referring to the franchise in general or something else that's more specific. Please edit your question to provide better context.